# What will this ruby function be returning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean

I have a code which calls a boolean function.

```
can_process = done_recently?(load)
```

Here is how the done_recently function looks.

```
def done_recently?(load)
      time_window = 10000
      load['terminatedAt'] && (load['terminatedAt'] > time_window.minutes.ago.utc.iso8601)
    end
```

In my json data, inside

> "load": [{ "terminatedAt": null }]

among lots of other data . This json data is converted into a hash before calling these functions.

What will the done_recently? function return(true/false)? I am new to ruby so i am getting a little confused. please help me out.

I have tried replicating in irb but got confused midway because of some errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your input is `{ "terminatedAt": null }` then

```
def done_recently?(load)
  time_window = 10000
  load['terminatedAt'] && (load['terminatedAt'] > time_window.minutes.ago.utc.iso8601)
end
```

will return `nil`. `nil` is returned because the first part of `load['terminatedAt'] && ...` evaluates to `nil` which is considered falsy and there for the second part after the `&&` will not be evaluated anymore and the `nil` is returned immediately.

Comment: If using Rails (As the Integer#minutes helpers look like), could be solved with `.present?`